# PyUSB AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'enumerate_devices'

Tags: python, pyusb

First time using PyUSB, trying to reverse engineer an eye-toy (Play Station) for OS X. Though I get the following error, when attempting to establish a testing collection.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "eye.py", line 5, in <module>
dev = usb.core.find(0x054C,0x0155)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 824, in find
return [d for d in device_iter(k, v)]
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 794, in device_iter
for dev in backend.enumerate_devices():
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'enumerate_devices'
```

Current code...

```
import usb.core, time, usb

dev = usb.core.find(0x054C,0x0155)

if dev is None:
  raise ValueError('Device not found')           # if device not found report an error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`usb.core.find` isn't used with positional arguments like that.

I'm guessing that you have  a vendor ID and a product ID.

If so, you should be doing this:

```
usb.core.find(idVendor= 0x054C, idProduct= 0x0155)
```

If you try to provide positional parameters, you're settings the values of `find_all` and  `backend`.

Comment: Thanks, well I get device not found. Though they're the right vendor and product ID.

Comment: @Hmm: If you're no longer getting an exception, that's a separate question. Also, be prepared to prove that you've got the right vendor and product code.

Comment: @Hmm: If you're no longer getting an exception, that's still a separate question.